# How to set environment variable in Azure for a App service

Tags: azure, environment-variables, azure-web-app-service, azure-webapps, azure-configuration

I have a .net Framework Web App running in Azure. 
In my code I have a line that gets an environment variable:

```
var x = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MY_Setting_Name");
```

How do I set/view this setting in the Azure portal? is it the same place as app settings? becuase I thought that was for the settings in the web-config file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just go to Configuration -> Application settings and create key value pairs that will be read by your application.

[image]

[image]

More info:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-common#configure-app-settings